# Get object type in runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic-typing

I have the code below. I get an object whose type I don't know. I have to check
three if conditions to check its type, then make the right cast.

Is there any way to get the object type at runtime, and make the cast,
without checking any if condition?

The object I have is `requirementTemplate`, and I have to check it with many types to get its type then make the cast.

```
if (requirementTemplate.GetType() == typeof(SRS_Requirement))
{
    ((SRS_Requirement)((TreeNodeInfo)ParentTreeNode.Tag).Handle).AssociatedFeature = ((SRS_Requirement)requirementTemplate).AssociatedFeature;
}
else if (requirementTemplate.GetType() == typeof(CRF_Requirement))
{
    ((CRF_Requirement)((TreeNodeInfo)ParentTreeNode.Tag).Handle).AssociatedFeature = customAttr.saveAttributesCustomList(AttributesCustomListCloned);
}
else if (requirementTemplate.GetType() == typeof(SAT_TestCase))
{
    ((SAT_TestCase)((TreeNodeInfo)ParentTreeNode.Tag).Handle).AssociatedFeature = ((SAT_TestCase)requirementTemplate).AssociatedFeature;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with 3 different C# versions? Which one is it?

Comment: Your code would be much, much clearer if you extracted `((TreeNodeInfo)ParentTreeNode.Tag).Handle` into a separate variable to start with. You should also consider using `is` instead of calling `GetType()`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use **`as`** keyword.
Check as [(C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

Comment: This is technically the correct answer, although it doesn't address the shockingly poor design implied by the wall of code.

Comment: I don't see how this will help with his design. He will still need to hard code the type for casting in order to access the AssociatedFeature property. An thus, still need all the if statements, which is what he wants to reduce... other answer (Interface) is much more appropriate

Comment: I would say this is the answer to "Is there any way to get the object type at runtime, and make the cast, without checking any if condition?" :D

Answer (score 2):

the most appropriate answer here would be to either implement a common interface, or override a virtual method from a common base-class, and use polymorphism to provide the implementation (from the various implementing classes) at runtime. Then your method becomes:

```
(blah.Handle).AssociatedFeature  = requirementTemplate.GetAssociatedFeature();
```

If the list is not exclusive (i.e. other implementations exist), then:

```
var feature = requirementTemplate as IHasAssociatedFeature;
if(feature != null) {
    (blah.Handle).AssociatedFeature = feature.GetAssociatedFeature();
}
```

you can do similar things on the left hand side too, or pass that in as context:

```
var feature = requirementTemplate as IHasAssociatedFeature;
if(feature != null) {
     feature.SetAssociatedFeature(blah);
}
```

(if necessary)

---

Another not-uncommon approach is to `switch` on an enum here:

```
switch(requirementTemplate.FeatureType) {
     case ...
}
```

one nice thing about this is that it can be either type-specific or instance-specific.